# MySQL fails to start after updating XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp, innodb

I recently updated my XAMPP version to be able to use PHP 7.
I had no problems migrating, so I copied the whole directory to my notebook to work on it.

There the MySQL service always crashed on startup. Having returned to my PC today I had to realize that MySQL won't start on my PC anymore.

```
2017-05-14 19:02:58 8200 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 2453615 and 2453615 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2453645 in the ib_logfiles!
2017-05-14 19:02:58 8200 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-05-14 19:02:58 8200 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-05-14 19:02:58 8200 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2017-05-14 19:02:58 8200 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace bnw/bnwv1_games uses space ID: 29 at filepath: .\bnw\bnwv1_games.ibd. Cannot open tablespace phpmyadmin/pma__export_templates which uses space ID: 29 at filepath: .\phpmyadmin\pma__export_templates.ibd
```

This should be the interesting part from the error log. A message later it suggests to set `innodb_force_recovery > 0`, but then it only complains about missing `db.MYI` (and also `MYD` and also for server, user, event after creating empty files).

Since the ib_logfiles log sequence number increases by 10 on every attempted start and I'm quite sure there is no corrupted data in the DB, I think it would be enough to manually reset it. How can I do this?

Edit: Complete error log (from another start): https://pastebin.com/T7GRgK4v

Answer (score 0):

Probably this issue is with the below line in [mysqld] section which somehow commented-out/removed from my.ini file:

```
key_buffer = 16M
```

After commenting this out this line will be:

```
#key_buffer = 16M
```

Please first check your Windows Event Viewer for more clues to the errors in XAMPP Control Panel.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't fix it. Windows Event Viewer doesn't give any further information, but I copied the whole error log here: https://pastebin.com/T7GRgK4v

Comment: Can You try this: 1) exit Xampp server  2) go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory  3 ) delete the ibdata1 file  4) restart xampp server

Comment: Or you can do this also: 1) Go to mysql/data/  2) Delete all random files (except the actual database folders)  3) Restart Apache and MySQL.

Comment: When I delete all the files it complains again about missing `user.MYI`

Answer (score 0):

Two issues...

- InnoDB had some trouble.  You changed `innodb_force_recovery`?  And you changed it back, I hope.
- MyISAM is having some kind of trouble with a table?  Then do `CHECK TABLE` on the table in question, then do `REPAIR TABLE` on that table.  That should fix and/or rebuild the `.MYI` (which contains the indexes for one MyISAM table).